# evaluate the record as condition and give true or false based on that in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, evaluate

i have a condition in one column and i have to evaluate it.
for example i have .

| condition |
| --- |
| male=male and 16<=50 |
| yes=yes and(male=male or male=female) |

i have this kind of column and i want to evaluate these condition that these conditions are true or false.

and what i want is

| condition | result |
| --- | --- |
| male=male and 71<=50 | false |
| yes=yes and(male=male or male=female) | True |

Comment: Does the `condition` column reference columns from the table where the condition is stored? If not, then what does `male` refer to? And why include conditions that are always true, like `16 <= 50` or `male = male`

Comment: yes that column is reference from another table and by running function and merging some content finally i got this column and nw i want to evaluate this as an expression

Comment: In the expression `male=male` it's unclear what the column reference and what the actual comparison value is.

Comment: here it is comparision for gender if i want gender as female then two possiblities are there 1) male=female(person is male so i got this in this case i want to get false ) and 2) female=female(then i want true) . i hope it is  clear now

Comment: can i do this by **execute**

Comment: If the conditions are given according to your question, this is impossible. As any code that you run will evaluate `male = male` as true. You need to at least change your expression to be valid SQL that contains constants and column references. Then you can use e.g. [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59406118) - I am inclined to mark this as a duplicate to that question actually.